# How to get started with visual basic and visual C++ in Visual Studio Community edition?

Tags: toolbox

Learning visual studio and visual c++ in microsoft visual studio environment

I have downloaded microsoft visual studio community free edition, when I work I dont see any toolbox in side bar to drag and drop tools on form.